What did the sheriff mean here?
Between 0:12 and 0:21 in https://youtu.be/5nUr3Flf8l4, did the sheriff say that

this visual artifact (or effect?) was very bland. was not invoking (or inmoting?) any emotion at all.

?
What does the visual artifact or (effect) mean here?
What's it about emotion here?

he said that his face showed no emotion

"His facial affect (whatever that means!) was very bland. He was not emoting any emotion at all." To say "emote an emotion" is tautology (saying the same thing twice).

This question can't be answered without watching the video, which isn't strictly a no-no but is a bad idea, and points toward the fact that it's not actually a question about language. It's not specifically in our rules that questions asking for transcription of audio are off-topic, but I feel like they should be.

I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about the workings of the English language, just about audio.

@AndyBonner They included a transcription in the question, but they got several of the words wrong.  Is this a Catch-22? You can't ask a question if you don't know English well, but it's specifically for people who are just learning English.

I would agree with AndyBonner if the question were about something more extensive than a phrase, but requests to confirm whether an OP has correctly heard a phrase should be on-topic, since the proper processing of a native speaker's pronunciation is part of language learning. Now OP knows to listen for the difference between visual and facial and between affect and artifact.

@Barmar "You can't ask a question if you don't know English well" —I think a survey of the many great questions that get asked here every day, with varying degrees of fluency, should show this isn't the case. It is true that you can't ask a question if you don't know English well enough to make the question clear. (I could right now ask clear questions in only about 2 "and a half" languages, on a good day!) My close-vote here might be going a bit rogue, as it's not an official reason stated in our help pages.

@AndyBonner But in this case, they tried to create a transcript. But because they couldn't understand what the man was saying, the transcript is wrong. How to solve that without a link to the video?

@Barmar Note, I didn't vote to close because most of the knowledge needed to answer the question was outside this site; that's just a bad idea (someone couldn't answer if Youtube were blocked on their network, or if they were finding this question much later and the link were dead). I voted to close because I don't think "what did they say?" questions are really about language. TimR disagrees with me and that's fine. If I felt strongly, which I don't, I could start a conversation in Meta.

@Barmar Ah, looks like it was already discussed, sort of, 5 years ago

Like the comment on that question, by the way, I'd say this question would be an excellent candidate for the chat room

This could also have a better title; I thought it was going to be about the meaning of the sheriff not artifact/affect/effect.

@AndyBonner  The cup was half full :-)  I would agree if the OP had asked for a "transcript" of a paragraph. But a request to clarify a single phrase I think should be not out of bounds, and such questions have indeed been accepted for quite a long while here.


His facial affect was very bland.

His face was blank, expressionless.
"facial affect" refers to the look on a face as it reveals mental state, such as surprise, anger, bewilderment, fear, amusement, awe, hatred, mania, etc.
It's a psychological/criminological term.

To add to your answer (feel free to edit this into the answer) definition of 'Affect' (reference below) "Affect is the external and dynamic manifestation of a person’s
internal emotional state, and hence is present in all individuals. It
may or may not match a person’s stated mood. Affect is judged in
terms of its type, intensity, range, variability, and degree of
correspondence to the content of conversation. Normal individuals
demonstrate a variety of emotions, of variable intensity, that usually
match and change in accordance with the thoughts and feelings being
verbally expressed."

From The Psychiatric Mental Status Examination, by Trzepacz and Baker. 'Bland' is one of the possibilities. " For example, a patient who describes
him- or herself as depressed may have an affect that is bland and
indifferent."

Yes, thank you for identifying the technical use of "affect", seemingly not in the other commentators' lexicon. Perhaps more familiar to those who have read in recent social sciences.

It is neither - he said "facial affect".
To affect can mean to display something, such as an emotion. The sheriff is saying that the suspect's face displayed little or no emotion ("bland" has a secondary dictionary definition of "showing no strong emotion"). It is generally believed that psychopaths show no emotion or remorse over killing so it feels like the sheriff is trying to support their arrest and belief that this is the right man.

Affect in this case is a noun. It doesn't make sense to say "to affect". It is a property of your face, basically

@roganjosh actually no - "facial affect" is a noun phrase. It's common in psychology. Lots of noun phrases contain verbs but phrases have internal logic so the meaning of the verb is relevant to my answer.
